# Unreachable Code in Tic Tac Toe Program

Tags: java

I've been researching "dead code" and "unreachable code" for awhile now and I still can't seem to figure out what's going on with this problem in my program. This is a snippet of what I have; the method "gameEnd()" which checks for winners in Tic Tac Toe:

```
private boolean gameEnd() {
    // Setting local variables
    int x = xMouseSquare;
    int y = yMouseSquare;
    int[][] g = gameBoard;
    int c = CPU;
    int h = HUMAN;

    // Checking for a winner

    /* Checking columns (xMouseSquare)
     * Enter the y value, the vertical value, first; then x, the horizontal value, second
     */

    // Set y equal to 0 and then add 1
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        // Set CPU c equal to 0
        c = 0;
        // Set x equal to 0 and then add 1
        for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            // Add CPU's value to the game board 
            c += g[x][y];

            // If statement returning the absolute value of CPU
            if (Math.abs(c) == 3) {
                // If these values are correct, return true; the game ends with CPU win horizontally
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    // If not, return false; game continues until all marks are filled
    return false;
    // Set y equal to 0 and then add 1
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        // This time, however, set HUMAN h equal to 0
        h = 0;
        // Set x equal to 0 and then add 1
        for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            // Then add HUMAN's value to the game board
            h += g[x][y];
            // If statement returning the absolute value of HUMAN
            if (Math.abs(h) == -3) {
                // If these values are correct, return true; the game ends with HUMAN win horizontally
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    // If not, return false; game continues until all marks are filled

    return false;
    {
        /* Checking rows (yMouseSquare)
         * Enter the x value, the horizontal value, first; then y, the vertical value, second
         */
        // Set x equal to 0 and then add 1
        for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            // Set CPU equal to 0
            c = 0;
            // Set y equal to 0 and then add 1
            for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                // Add CPU's value to the game board, but with y and then x
                c += g[y][x];
                // If statement returning the absolute value of CPU
                if (Math.abs(c) == 3) {
                    // If these values are correct, return true; the game ends with CPU win vertically
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        // If not, return false; game continues until all marks are filled
        return false;
        {
            // Set x equal to 0 and then add 1
            for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                // This time, however, set HUMAN h equal to 0
                h = 0;
                // Set y equal to 0 and then add 1
                for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {   
                    // Then add HUMAN's value to the game board
                    h += g[x][y];
                    // If statement returning the absolute value of HUMAN
                    if (Math.abs(h) == -3) {
                        // If these values are correct, return true; the game ends with CPU win vertically
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            // If not, return false; game continues until all marks are filled
            return false;
        }
    }
}
} // error on this bracket; but when I remove it, some of the code above becomes unreachable. Can anyone point to what I'm doing wrong?
```

Comment: The error will be much easier to find if you format (indent) your code correctly. Your IDE can even do it for you.

Comment: First, fix your indentation to match up with your brackets -- it's very much wrong right now. If you're using a good editor, it should be able to do this for you automatically.

Comment: When you `return false;` like that, you exit the method. 2/3rds of your code will never be executed (aka unreachable).

Comment: The problem is your first `return false;` The method will return false and be done. All of the code below that line can never be executed. Look at a Java tutorial how methods work. E.g. [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Answer (score 4):

If it was indented properly, I think it would show that the first occurrence of 'return false' will always be executed if the first instance of 'return true' was not hit, hence all remaining code is never reached.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem right here

```
// If not, return false; game continues until all marks are filled
        return false; <-- code exits here, everything below will not run.
        {
            // Set x equal to 0 and then add 1
            for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
...
```